# How to untar file with UTF-8 special characters in Windows

Tags: windows, tar, 7-zip, utf-8, special-characters

I want extract a TAR file with special characters UTF-8 and when open it with WinRAR and PeaZip show filename like mark question and when extract it with WinRAR and 7-Zip file name change to underscore instead of filename UTF-8 so are there any way to utar it to extract it with support filename UTF-8.

Comment: [NT-based Windows stores the long file names on disk in Unicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx). Moreover, filenames in NT-based Windows systems are all treated as Unicode  in the current code page internally...